# Django - Is correct this custom FileField?

Tags: django, django-models

I just wrote a custom `ImageField` (I don't really know if this way is correct).
The code is above:

```
from django.db import router
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageField, FileField


def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "/".join([router.db_for_read(User),  # DATABASE ALIAS
                    instance._meta.app_label,  # APP NAME
                    instance._meta.module_name,   # MODEL NAME
                    filename])  # FILE NAME


class NMImageField(ImageField):
    """docstring for NMImageField"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['upload_to'] = content_file_name
        super(NMImageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I just want a ImageField with a default `upload_to` location.

The long version:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import router
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageField, FileField


def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "/".join([router.db_for_read(User),  # DATABASE ALIAS
                    instance._meta.app_label,  # APP NAME
                    instance._meta.module_name,   # MODEL NAME
                    filename])  # FILE NAME

class AnyModel(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
```

What I wanted to do:

```
from django.db import models
from myproject.utils import NMImageField

class AnyModel(models.Model):
    Image = NMImageField()
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but your custom class really isn't accomplishing anything. There's no reason why you couldn't simply put your `content_file_name` function in a shared module and re-use it wherever you need. It's also less code overall.

Comment: This code won't be used only for me, and I think that is easier to remember import a custom field than set the `upload_to` argument, and is possible that new features will be added to this custom field.

Comment: If it works for you, go for it. Just make sure you don't change the default signature of the field so that you break forward compatibility.